# How to not wait for a long running async task method?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I know it's not a good practice to use an async void. But what if I don't want to wait for a result of a long running task?

I have a scenario where I need to insert some values to the database and return a result. But I don't need to wait to finish all the insert before returning an instance of an object.

If you look at the code below, there's a method that initializes the DataService. But during the initialization part it needs to insert code description and headers to the database. I would like to return the dataService and I don't care if the code description and headers are finished inserting.

```
async Task<DataService> InitializeAsync()
{
   _dataService = new DataService(); 
   await _dataService.InsertCodeDescriptionAsync();
   await _dataService.InserHeadersAsync(); 
   return _dataService; 
}
```

I think I can do that by changing InsertCodeDescriptionAsync and InsertHeadersAsync to be an async void function. But that's not good according to some articles I read. So what would be the best thing to do in this scenario?

Update: 
The goal is to initialize the dataService and do the insert in the background.

Comment: *But what if I don't want to wait for a result of a long running process* -- then don't `await` it?

Comment: If you don't want to wait for them, why is the function even `async` in the first place? Just return the `_dataService` directly without encapsulating it in a `Task`.

Comment: Do you mean you don't need the result of the process but you just need it to be completed before going forward? Because if not, then you don't need the `await` at all.

Comment: So, you don't even care if they complete or not, with error or success or if the process blows because of it. Is that it?

Comment: Well, there's appropriate error handling inside the insert  methods. But at the moment, I don't need to know if it finished inserting. By the way, that's not the actual code. The actual code is way complex than that. I just want to understand the best approach.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could get rid of `async` and `await` altogether:

```
DataService Initialize()
{
    _dataService = new DataService(); 
    var fireAndForgetTask1 = _dataService.InsertCodeDescriptionAsync();
    var fireAndForgetTask2 = _dataService.InsertHeadersAsync(); 
    return _dataService; 
}
```

This way you avoid any compiler warnings, and communicate your intent to ignore the results of the tasks to future maintainers of your code.

Comment: I can't believe it worked. Initially I thought that doing what you wrote will just assign the task to the variable fireAndForgetTask1 and will not execute until something awaited it.

Comment: @Lance tasks are normally **hot**, meaning that they are already started after their creation. To make a **cold** task you need to make use of the `Task` constructor, that is rare and not recommended.

Answer (score 3):

Well my suggested answer is two-fold:

Simple answer: If you don't need to await a task, then don't await it.

But the consequences will be that the execution contexts of your main code and your not awaited tasks will diverge and if an exception happens in either of the methods you'll never know in your code. I suppose you call the two methods for a reason and they do something that'll eventually be needed by your code but not right away?

If so then I would suggest to still use `await` even if you don't need the methods to complete right away. This will however guarantee that the methods have completed at some point and the performance impact is often minimal, especially in a multi-threading scenario, since that's when the async magic kicks in and frees a lot of CPU time while waiting.

If you want to have both speed and reliability you could do something like

```
(DataService, Task) InitializeAsync()
{
 _dataService = new DataService(); 
 var t = Task.WhenAll(_dataService.InsertCodeDescriptionAsync(), _dataService.InserHeadersAsync());
 return (_dataService, t); 
}
```

which will give you the dataService right away but also a Task that you can use to await the completion of your initialization methods when you need them to be completed.

Comment: You are complicating the API. I would prefer to store the task as a property of the `DataService`, so that it can be inspected later, possibly at a different part of the program.

Answer (score 2):

don't await the tasks you don't want to wait for. something like below will work for you.

```
Task<DataService> InitializeAsync()
{
   _dataService = new DataService(); 
   _dataService.InsertCodeDescriptionAsync();
   _dataService.InserHeadersAsync(); 
   return Task.FromResult(_dataService); 
}
```